# caffe - network produce zero gradient and not learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I'm training caffenet with multilabel data. However the lost is not decreasing during training phase. I'm now trying to check if the `backward()` is not working properly. I have this code to check if there is a gradient.

```
    import numpy as np
    import os.path as osp
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    from pprint import pprint
    from copy import copy

    % matplotlib inline

    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (6, 6)

    caffe_root = '../'  # this file is expected to be in {caffe_root}/examples
    sys.path.append(caffe_root + 'python')
    import caffe # If you get "No module named _caffe", either you have not built pycaffe or you have the wrong path.

    from caffe import layers as L, params as P # Shortcuts to define the net prototxt.

    sys.path.append("pycaffe/layers") # the datalayers we will use are in this directory.
    sys.path.append("pycaffe") # the tools file is in this folder

    import tools #this contains some tools that we need

    # set data root directory, e.g:
    peta_root = osp.join('/root/data/PETA/')

    # these are the PASCAL classes, we'll need them later.
    #classes = np.asarray(['aeroplane', 'bicycle', 'bird', 'boat', 'bottle', 'bus', 'car', 'cat', 'chair', 'cow', 'diningtable', 'dog', 'horse', 'motorbike', 'person', 'pottedplant', 'sheep', 'sofa', 'train', 'tvmonitor'])

# make sure we have the caffenet weight downloaded.
if not os.path.isfile(caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel'):
    print("Downloading pre-trained CaffeNet model...")
    !../scripts/download_model_binary.py ../models/bvlc_reference_caffenet

# initialize caffe for gpu mode
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
caffe.set_device(1)

# helper function for common structures
def conv_relu(bottom, ks, nout, stride=1, pad=0, group=1):
    conv = L.Convolution(bottom, kernel_size=ks, stride=stride,
                                num_output=nout, pad=pad, group=group)#,weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    return conv, L.ReLU(conv, in_place=True)

# another helper function
def fc_relu(bottom, nout):
    fc = L.InnerProduct(bottom, num_output=nout)
    return fc, L.ReLU(fc, in_place=True)

# yet another helper function
def max_pool(bottom, ks, stride=1):
    return L.Pooling(bottom, pool=P.Pooling.MAX, kernel_size=ks, stride=stride)

# main netspec wrapper
def caffenet_multilabel(data_layer_params, datalayer):
    # setup the python data layer 
    n = caffe.NetSpec()
    n.data, n.label = L.Python(module = 'peta_multilabel_datalayers', layer = datalayer, 
                               ntop = 2, param_str=str(data_layer_params))

    # the net itself
    n.conv1, n.relu1 = conv_relu(n.data, 11, 96, stride=4)
    n.pool1 = max_pool(n.relu1, 3, stride=2)
    n.norm1 = L.LRN(n.pool1, local_size=5, alpha=1e-4, beta=0.75)
    n.conv2, n.relu2 = conv_relu(n.norm1, 5, 256, pad=2, group=2)
    n.pool2 = max_pool(n.relu2, 3, stride=2)
    n.norm2 = L.LRN(n.pool2, local_size=5, alpha=1e-4, beta=0.75)
    n.conv3, n.relu3 = conv_relu(n.norm2, 3, 384, pad=1)
    n.conv4, n.relu4 = conv_relu(n.relu3, 3, 384, pad=1, group=2)
    n.conv5, n.relu5 = conv_relu(n.relu4, 3, 256, pad=1, group=2)
    n.pool5 = max_pool(n.relu5, 3, stride=2)
    n.fc6, n.relu6 = fc_relu(n.pool5, 4096)
    n.drop6 = L.Dropout(n.relu6, in_place=True)
    n.fc7, n.relu7 = fc_relu(n.drop6, 4096)
    n.drop7 = L.Dropout(n.relu7, in_place=True)
    n.score = L.InnerProduct(n.drop7, num_output=2)
    n.loss = L.SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss(n.score, n.label)

    return str(n.to_proto())

workdir = './peta_multilabel_with_datalayer'
if not os.path.isdir(workdir):
    os.makedirs(workdir)

solverprototxt = tools.CaffeSolver(trainnet_prototxt_path = osp.join(workdir, "trainnet.prototxt"), testnet_prototxt_path = osp.join(workdir, "valnet.prototxt"))
solverprototxt.sp['display'] = "1"
solverprototxt.sp['base_lr'] = "0.0001"
solverprototxt.write(osp.join(workdir, 'solver.prototxt'))

# write train net.
with open(osp.join(workdir, 'trainnet.prototxt'), 'w') as f:
    # provide parpeta_multilabel_with_datalayerameters to the data layer as a python dictionary. Easy as pie!
    data_layer_params = dict(batch_size = 128, im_shape = [227, 227], split = 'train', peta_root = peta_root)
    f.write(caffenet_multilabel(data_layer_params, 'PetaMultilabelDataLayerSync'))

# write validation net.
with open(osp.join(workdir, 'valnet.prototxt'), 'w') as f:
    data_layer_params = dict(batch_size = 128, im_shape = [227, 227], split = 'val', peta_root = peta_root)
    f.write(caffenet_multilabel(data_layer_params, 'PetaMultilabelDataLayerSync'))

solver = caffe.SGDSolver(osp.join(workdir, 'solver.prototxt'))
#solver.net.copy_from(caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel')
solver.test_nets[0].share_with(solver.net)
#solver.step(1)

solver.net.top_names
solver.net.backward()
solver.step(1)
print solver.net.params['fc6'][0].data[...]
print solver.net.blobs['fc6'].data[...]
print solver.net.blobs['fc6'].diff[...]
```

However the output of gradient seems to be zero and the weight is not update at all.

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Anyone knows what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the values of your `params`: they are all zeros. You did not define `filler`s for your layers, thus all you get is zeros.
Define random initializers for the weights and run again.

---

Running only `backward()` is meaningless - the loss is computed during `forward()` pass, there is no loss information propagated through the net for the backward pass to use.
Call `forward()` **before** `backward()` to make one *complete* forward-backward pass.

Comment: yes. but i have `solver.step(1)` which provide `forward()` and `backward()`