# Accuracy does not change

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, classification, caffe, digits

I am trying to train a binary classification model in caffe that tells if an input image is a dog or background. I have 8223 positive samples and 33472 negative samples. My validation set contains 1200 samples, 600 of each class. In fact, my positives are snippets taken from MS-COCO dataset. All images are resized so the biiger dimension does not exceed 92 and the smaller dimension is not smaller than 44. After creating the LMDB files using create_imagenet.sh (resize=false), I started training with the solver and train .prototxt's below. The problem is that I am getting a constant accuracy (0.513333 or 0.486667) which indicates that the network is not learning anything.
I hope that someone is able to help
Thank you in advanced

solver file:

```
    iter_size: 32
    test_iter: 600
    test_interval: 20
    base_lr: 0.001
    display: 2
    max_iter: 20000
    lr_policy: "step"
    gamma: 0.99
    stepsize: 700
    momentum: 0.9
    weight_decay: 0.0001
    snapshot: 40
    snapshot_prefix: "/media/DATA/classifiers_data/dog_object/models/"
    solver_mode: GPU
    net: "/media/DATA/classifiers_data/dog_object/net.prototxt"
    solver_type: ADAM
```

train.prototxt:

```
    layer {
      name: "train-data"
      type: "Data"
      top: "data"
      top: "label"
      include {
        phase: TRAIN
      }

      data_param {
        source: "/media/DATA/classifiers_data/dog_object/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb"
        batch_size: 1
        backend: LMDB
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "val-data"
      type: "Data"
      top: "data"
      top: "label"
      include {
        phase: TEST
      }
      data_param {
        source: "/media/DATA/classifiers_data/dog_object/ilsvrc12_val_lmdb"
        batch_size: 1
        backend: LMDB
      }
    }

    layer {
      name: "scale"
      type: "Power"
      bottom: "data"
      top: "scale"
      power_param {
        scale: 0.00390625

      }
    }

    layer {
      bottom: "scale"
      top: "conv1_1"
      name: "conv1_1"
      type: "Convolution"
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 64
        pad: 1
        kernel_size: 3
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
      }
    }
    layer {
      bottom: "conv1_1"
      top: "conv1_1"
      name: "relu1_1"
      type: "ReLU"
    }
    layer {
      bottom: "conv1_1"
      top: "conv1_2"
      name: "conv1_2"
      type: "Convolution"
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 64
        pad: 1
        kernel_size: 3
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
      }
    }

    layer {
      bottom: "conv1_2"
      top: "conv1_2"
      name: "relu1_2"
      type: "ReLU"
    }
    layer {
      name: "spatial_pyramid_pooling"
      type: "SPP"
      bottom: "conv1_2"
      top: "spatial_pyramid_pooling"
      spp_param {
        pool: MAX
        pyramid_height : 4
      }
    }
    layer {
      bottom: "spatial_pyramid_pooling"
      top: "fc6"
      name: "fc6"
      type: "InnerProduct"
      inner_product_param {
        num_output: 64
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
      }
    }
    layer {
      bottom: "fc6"
      top: "fc6"
      name: "relu6"
      type: "ReLU"
    }
    layer {
      bottom: "fc6"
      top: "fc6"
      name: "drop6"
      type: "Dropout"
      dropout_param {
        dropout_ratio: 0.5
      }
    }
    layer {
      bottom: "fc6"
      top: "fc7"
      name: "fc7"
      type: "InnerProduct"
      inner_product_param {
        num_output: 2
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "loss"
      type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
      bottom: "fc7"
      bottom: "label"
      top: "loss"
    }
    layer {
      name: "accuracy/top1"
      type: "Accuracy"
      bottom: "fc7"
      bottom: "label"
      top: "accuracy"
      include: { phase: TEST }

    }
```

part of training log:

I1125 15:52:36.604038  2326 solver.cpp:362] Iteration 40, Testing net (#0)

I1125 15:52:36.604071  2326 net.cpp:723] Ignoring source layer train-data

I1125 15:52:47.127979  2326 solver.cpp:429]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.486667

I1125 15:52:47.128067  2326 solver.cpp:429]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.694894 (* 1 = 0.694894 loss)

I1125 15:52:48.937928  2326 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 40 (0.141947 iter/s, 14.0897s/2 iter), loss = 0.67717

I1125 15:52:48.938014  2326 solver.cpp:261]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.655692 (* 1 = 0.655692 loss)

I1125 15:52:48.938040  2326 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 40, lr = 0.001

I1125 15:52:52.858757  2326 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 42 (0.510097 iter/s, 3.92083s/2 iter), loss = 0.673962

I1125 15:52:52.858841  2326 solver.cpp:261]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.653978 (* 1 = 0.653978 loss)

I1125 15:52:52.858875  2326 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 42, lr = 0.001

I1125 15:52:56.581573  2326 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 44 (0.53723 iter/s, 3.7228s/2 iter), loss = 0.673144

I1125 15:52:56.581656  2326 solver.cpp:261]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.652269 (* 1 = 0.652269 loss)

I1125 15:52:56.581689  2326 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 44, lr = 0.001

I1125 15:53:00.192082  2326 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 46 (0.553941 iter/s, 3.61049s/2 iter), loss = 0.669606

I1125 15:53:00.192167  2326 solver.cpp:261]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.650559 (* 1 = 0.650559 loss)

I1125 15:53:00.192200  2326 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 46, lr = 0.001

I1125 15:53:04.195417  2326 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 48 (0.499585 iter/s, 4.00332s/2 iter), loss = 0.674327

I1125 15:53:04.195691  2326 solver.cpp:261]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.648808 (* 1 = 0.648808 loss)

I1125 15:53:04.195736  2326 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 48, lr = 0.001

I1125 15:53:07.856842  2326 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 50 (0.546265 iter/s, 3.66123s/2 iter), loss = 0.661835

I1125 15:53:07.856925  2326 solver.cpp:261]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.647097 (* 1 = 0.647097 loss)

I1125 15:53:07.856957  2326 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 50, lr = 0.001

I1125 15:53:11.681635  2326 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 52 (0.522906 iter/s, 3.82478s/2 iter), loss = 0.66071

I1125 15:53:11.681720  2326 solver.cpp:261]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.743264 (* 1 = 0.743264 loss)

I1125 15:53:11.681754  2326 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 52, lr = 0.001

I1125 15:53:15.544859  2326 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 54 (0.517707 iter/s, 3.86319s/2 iter), loss = 0.656414

I1125 15:53:15.544950  2326 solver.cpp:261]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.643741 (* 1 = 0.643741 loss)

I1125 15:53:15.544986  2326 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 54, lr = 0.001

I1125 15:53:19.354320  2326 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 56 (0.525012 iter/s, 3.80943s/2 iter), loss = 0.645277

I1125 15:53:19.354404  2326 solver.cpp:261]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.747059 (* 1 = 0.747059 loss)

I1125 15:53:19.354431  2326 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 56, lr = 0.001

I1125 15:53:23.195466  2326 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 58 (0.520681 iter/s, 3.84112s/2 iter), loss = 0.677604

I1125 15:53:23.195549  2326 solver.cpp:261]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.640145 (* 1 = 0.640145 loss)

I1125 15:53:23.195575  2326 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 58, lr = 0.001

I1125 15:53:25.140920  2326 solver.cpp:362] Iteration 60, Testing net (#0)

I1125 15:53:25.140965  2326 net.cpp:723] Ignoring source layer train-data

I1125 15:53:35.672775  2326 solver.cpp:429]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.513333

I1125 15:53:35.672937  2326 solver.cpp:429]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.69323 (* 1 = 0.69323 loss)

I1125 15:53:37.635395  2326 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 60 (0.138503 iter/s, 14.4401s/2 iter), loss = 0.655983

I1125 15:53:37.635478  2326 solver.cpp:261]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.638368 (* 1 = 0.638368 loss)

I1125 15:53:37.635512  2326 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 60, lr = 0.001

I1125 15:53:41.458472  2326 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 62 (0.523143 iter/s, 3.82305s/2 iter), loss = 0.672996

I1125 15:53:41.458555  2326 solver.cpp:261]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.753101 (* 1 = 0.753101 loss)

I1125 15:53:41.458588  2326 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 62, lr = 0.001

I1125 15:53:45.299643  2326 solver.cpp:242] Iteration 64 (0.520679 iter/s, 3.84114s/2 iter), loss = 0.668675

I1125 15:53:45.299737  2326 solver.cpp:261]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.634894 (* 1 = 0.634894 loss)

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:
1. Your test set contains 1200 samples, but you are validating on only 600 each time: `test_iter`*`batch_size`=600. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33786620/1714410) for more details.
2. Did you shuffle your training data when you created your lmdb? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37659171/1714410) for more details.
3. How do you init your weights? there seems to be no call for `filler`s in your prototxt file. If you do not explicitly define `filler`s, your weights are init to zero. It's a very difficult starting point for SGD. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47280560/1714410) for more details.
4. Have you tried setting `debug_info: true` in your solver and looking into the debug log to trace the root cause of you problem? See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40510706/1714410) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help

1. I have used 'test_iter: 600' just in sake of speed. For now I have increased the validation set to 1800 samples and changed 'test_iter: 1800'

2. My training data are well shuffled

3. I have tried 'xavier' and 'gaussian' with different std's but the results did not changed

4. I tried the 'debug_info: true' as mentioned in the answer. I did not find any nan or zero diff's. I am not sure, but L2 values seem to be ok.

5. I tried different solver types and learning rates, but it did not help. I hope I can show my log, but it is too long.

Comment: Could it be that I am using an imbalanced dataset (8223 positives to 33472 negatives)?

Comment: @MoMo I have two more concerns: (1) Imbalanced data as you already noted. (2) `batch_size: 1` seems very small. Have you tried increasing the batch size?

Comment: Can you artificially "balance" the data? That is in the text file listing all your examples (the input to `convert_imageset`), can you duplicate the lines of the positive examples such that the number of positives will match the number of negatives?

Comment: I will balance the dataset and comment what comes out. Regarding the 'batch_size: 1', I have 'iter_size: 32' in the solver file. AFAIK, it accumulates the gradient from 32 samples and update the weights based on the average.

Comment: @MoMo You are correct regarding [`iter_size`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36526959/1714410)

Comment: I conducted multiple experiments. First, I reduced the negatives to 21000 and then to 11000. It didn't help in both cases. Then, I added a third conv layer on top of the first two layers and fine-tuned these two from a pre-trained VGG16 caffemodel. In the case of 21000 it didn't help. But interestingly the accuracy started to go up (0.83 now) with 11000 negatives. Now, I will augment the positives to reach ~30000 and try the balanced data-set with fine-tuning. I will comment the results.